# Windows- Pyinstaller unless folder contains file appear error “failed to execute script"

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, executable, pyinstaller

I have a problem to over come the following error, when i am running my program packed using pyinstallet into standalone executable.

[image]

In the program i am using an icon file to set iconbitmap. The file is located in the same folder as the python script.

```
master = Tk()
master.wm_title("P&P Util ")
master.iconbitmap('logo.ico')
```

In addition i am adding and icon to the executable in the packing process.

```
pyinstaller -F -w -i "C:\temp\Util\logo.ico" main.py
```

Now after some testing i located that when i add file itself to the packed executable, the program is running without any issues. I understand that i need to change the way i am using the file but i don't know how.
Your advice will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is crashing because you have not added the "logo.ico" file to the package, so when `master.iconbitmap('logo.ico')` looks for the icon, it is not there.  With the command `-i 'C:\temp\Util\logo.ico'` you are telling pyinstaller to set that icon file as the windows icon, but this is not the same as including it in the package.  To do that try including this in your pyinstaller command:

```
--add-data "C:\temp\Util\logo.ico;."
```

The "." after the semi-colon tells pyinstaller where to put the file.  In this case it will put it into the same folder as the .exe file.

Comment: didn't work, as pyinstaller help says the way to use --add-data is 

  [--add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>]

 I ran the following:
 
  pyinstaller -F -w  --add-data "logo.ico;logo.ico" main.py

Unfortunately still got the same error

Comment: @Ilazar1x Sorry, I left out the second part of that command.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, maybe you can advice me in one more thing. After i used your suggestion, the pyinstaller adds the logo file into the executable. How do i know, when i run the installer without parameter "-F" i see the logo file in the created folder.

Unfortunately when i run the installer with parameter "-F"  created file activation fail with the same error "Failed to execute script".
Can you advice how to proceed?